# Most efficient way of making android.net.wifi.ScanResult a Comparable?

Tags: android, performance, android-wifi, comparable

I want to sort android wifi ScanResult objects by BSSID levels. What would be the most efficient way to do that? Do I have to create my own Comparable ScanResult and write code to convert to/from ScanResult?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating your own `Comparator` will probably be more straightforward. Assuming you have some sort of Collection containing the ScanResults (`list` in the example below):

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<ScanResult>() {
    @Override public int compare(ScanResult lhs, ScanResult rhs) {
        // add your sorting logic
    } 
});
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what I needed. So in terms of performance, that beats writing your own class and converting? I need to do it a lot of times...

Comment: Intuitively I'd say that's indeed the case, but admittedly I'm no expert on that area. There are some interesting Q/A's regarding this subject on SO though; have a search for them. If you need multiple sets with identical types sorted, I'd extract the Comparator to a non-anonymous object.